# In Dead Space 3, is there a way to acquire more than one copy of the unique weapon frames?

Tags: dead-space-3

In Dead Space 3, unlike the 2 previous games, you can craft and customise your own weapons to your personal tastes.

As you play through the game, you will get to find some unique "frames", which grant special stats bonus, unlike the regular frames which don't do anything special (taken from [Dead Space 3 Fandom page about Weapon Parts](https://deadspace.fandom.com/wiki/Weapon_Parts#Frames)):

- Weller's Compact Frame: A frame for one-handed weapons, has built in RLD +4. Only supports Top tools.
- Hammond's Heavy Frame: A frame for two-handed weapons, has built in CLP +3. Only supports Top tools.
- EarthGov Compact Frame: A frame for one-handed weapons, has built in SPD +3.
- S.C.A.F. Heavy Frame: A frame for two-handed weapons, has built in DMG +3.

These stats boosts look very helpful to make your customised weapons even stronger. However, you can find only one copy of each and they can't be crafted, which means only one of your weapons can have it.

Is there any way to acquire more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, you can duplicate them and craft them like any regular weapon parts

There is two ways to acquire as many of them as you need.

---

The first solution is probably the most well-known. It is also the solution that is suggested to craft unique weapons (such as the Devil Horns), in case you accidentally dismantle them.

First of all:

- Go to a bench.
- Open the crafting view.
- Select the weapon which has the unique frame installed on it.
- Create a Custom Blueprint of the weapon.
- Go to the blueprints view.
- You can now craft a duplicate version of your weapon with the same frame installed (but you still can't craft the frame as a standalone weapon part).

[image: A blueprint of my Plasma Cutter, which is equipped with the unique Compact Earth Gov Frame]

---

The second solution requires the first solution and allows you to craft the unique frames like any weapon part:

- Go to a bench.
- Open the crafting view.
- Select the weapon which has the unique frame installed on it.
- Create a Custom Blueprint of the weapon.

Now you have 2 choices:

- Go to the blueprints view.
- Craft a duplicate version of your weapon.
- Dismantle it.
- Return to the blueprints view and craft it again for free (since you dismantled it, you already have all the required parts).

Or:

- Dismantle your main weapon with the unique frame.
- Go to the blueprints view.
- Craft it again for free (since you dismantled it, you already have all the required parts).

[image: Recrafting my Plasma Cutter for free using my blueprint]

The first solution costs more resources. The second one is resource free if you already have weapons with the frame equipped, but might be scary because you might be dismantling your beloved weapon.

After doing that, you can now craft the unique frame in the weapon crafting view. Repeat it with all the unique frames, and you'll be able to craft every single one of them.

[image: The weapon crafting view, where you have to select a frame to craft a weapon. Notice the fact that I can select all of the unique frames: Compact Earth Gov Frame, Heavy S.C.A.F. Frame, Weller's Compact Frame, Hammond's Heavy Frame, and even the Devil's Hand which is useless]